# MouseListener in Java Swing sometimes not respond

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I've implemented right mouse click for open menu listener on my main Jframe, it works fine except one problem. One out of 5 (give or take) clicks it not responding, this can be very annoying for the user. Here is my code:

```
contentPane = new JPanel();
contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) 
            {
                //Do Stuff
            }
        }
    });
```

Can you please help me

Comment: One out of 5 in a row? Or just every 5 occurrences?

Comment: Could be that the EventDispatchingThread is been prevented from running because of long running process??

Comment: Are you sure you want `MouseEvent.BUTTON3`? Isn't a right-click typically `BUTTON2`?

Comment: One out of 5: Usually works, but some times does not.
For example 8 clicks OK, 2 Not... it`s looks like random, but there is no random things in here.

MouseEvent.BUTTON2 is middle click.

Comment: @Mong134 - You're right, but I think `e.isPopupTrigger()` is a better option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. **You won't get clicks from sub-components of `contentPane`.**

   I think your problem is that you have added things to your panel. When the user clicks at regions occupied by a sub-component, that sub-component get's the click event.

   *Quick fix: I would recommend you to add the same mouse listener to all sub-components.*
2. **You are not "clicking"**

   A click is when the mouse is pressed and release really quickly. If you are not careful you might get events for (for instance) "pressed, moved, released" instead of "clicked".

   *Quick fix: use `mouseReleased` event instead.*

Comment: I believe this is it, since he did mention he has an *OpenMenu* component. Asker has to add his mouselistener to **that** component.

Comment: Hum, I see only a panel and missing mouse events. What is executing in the might have something todo with it but I think my answer still applies.

Comment: Wow, Thank you! Never thought of it. This was my problem, when i moved just little bit it didn't worked.

Comment: Not specific to menus, I've often hit similar situations over the years.  *IF* the op were clicking into open regions, then carefully looking at the position of the mouse by monitoring the x,y of each press, release, and click event, he'll notice that the mouse will have moved by a single pixel or more between press and release.  This invalidates the click criteria.  In all such occurrences I've had so far, in no cases where a click failed were the x,y identical.  My solution was to ignore click, and keep track of the x,y of press and release, and distances from each. Open regions only.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code instead:

```
private MouseAdapter listener = new MouseAdapter() {

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        if (downer) {
            downer = false;
            if (new Rectangle(e.getComponent().getLocationOnScreen(), e.getComponent().getSize())
                    .contains(e.getLocationOnScreen())) {
                downer = false;
                // CODE
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                     public void run(){
                         //Your Listener code
                     }
                }).start();

                /// COde
            }
        }
    }

    boolean downer = false;

    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
        downer = true;
    }
};
```

This code only reacts if you press on the component and release on the component AND starts a new Thread for the custom task. This should work allways, because the AWT Thread isnt blocked with long calculations.